# Need to reduce the execution time of my C++ code

Tags: c++

So I need to write a program that summarizes numbers from console input. Numbers can be embedded in strings *(e.g. hello134 or hi -12)*.  Here is the code that works perfectly fine, but exceeds time limit (>1s).

So, how can I reduce executing time? Here is the test that my program fails to pass: https://pastebin.com/HNL9Vz7E

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string line;
    long p = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int b, e;
    long long sum = 0;
    while (getline(cin, line))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < line.size(); i++)
        {
            if (isdigit(line[i]) || line[i] == '-' && isdigit(line[i + 1]))
            {
                b = i;
                while (isdigit(line[++i]))
                {}
                e = i;
                p = stoi(line.substr(b, b - e));
                sum += p;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << sum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest using a regular expression to pull all numbers out of the string.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)

Comment: Your code is not correct. If the final character is a "-", you will access the element one of the end of the `string`.

Comment: Do not call `stoi` -- creating a number given digits is done with a simple loop.  Do not call `substr`, as that creates a new string.  Instead, use indices (`start_of_number`, `end_of_number`) and figure out the number given the starting position and ending positions.

Comment: Enable and read the warnings

Comment: @MarkRansom
Thank you for your comment. 
Would you mind providing some simple example on how to do something similar using regex?

Comment: @MarkRansom I tried using regex and my examples where much slower than this code: http://quick-bench.com/Fpb82-OGIot4xOPatM8aHzy7KXk

Comment: Don't use `isdigit`.  The `isdigit` function goes through locales, which takes time.  Use your own comparison, such as `((line[i] >= '0') && (line[i] <= '9'))`.

Comment: Create a constant integer temporary variable to contain `line.size()`.  The size of the line doesn't change in the loop and you are calling the function every iteration.

Comment: First how about writing what exactly the program should do: Sum up digit by digit? Or should consecutive digits be read as a decimal number? Are there negative numbers?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I'd be very surprised if `line.size()` didn't simply return a member variable, so the optimizer should turn it into a simple variable access already.

Comment: @Superlokkus
Program should extract numbers (yes, consecutive digits should be read as numbers), and yes, there are negatives.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews
Thank you so much! This little thing did the trick.

Comment: @MarkRansom Depends on the optimization.  At low optimization levels, I expect the loop to call the function.  On higher levels, I expect the compiler to execute the function once and place the result into a temporary variable or register.  IMHO, helping out the compiler is a good thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be the line with

```
line.substr(b, b - e)
```

I think it should be

```
line.substr(b, e - b)
```

instead. It always copies huge strings in this line. 
It takes less than a millisecond on mine with that sample file but also far away from a second with the unchanged code. And: Regex is much slower than doing it your way.

Comment: I rewrote the whole thing using regex and it didn't even pass 1st execution time test, so yes, it turned out to be way slower. 
Tho i still need to optimise the code above. The testing utility shows >1s exec time&

Comment: But on my system I get around 1400 loops / sec over your example file (means 1 cycle < 1ms)...  so values > 1sec are strange (measured with i7-6820HQ, 2,7GHz)